# RecyclerView | OnItemClickListener With Shared Transition

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, transition, onitemclicklistener

I want for my app a shared transition. For this I need a `OnItemClickListener`. I've searched for a while, but I haven't found anything for me.

Here is my `Adapter` with `ViewHolder`:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.PostViewHolder>{

List<Post> posts;


public ListAdapter(List<Post> posts) {
    Log.d("ListAdapter", "");
    this.posts = posts;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d("getItemCount", "");
    return posts.size();
}

@Override
public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    Log.d("onCreateView", "");
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.insert_layout, viewGroup, false);
    PostViewHolder pvh = new PostViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder postViewHolder, int i) {
    Log.d("onBindView", "");
    postViewHolder.username.setText(posts.get(i).getUsername());
    postViewHolder.text.setText(posts.get(i).getText());
    postViewHolder.time.setText(Long.toString(posts.get(i).getTime()));
    postViewHolder.postPhoto.setImageResource(posts.get(i).returnIMG());
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    Log.d("onAttached", "");
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}


public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CardView cv;
    TextView username;
    TextView time;
    TextView text;
    ImageView postPhoto;

    PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Log.d("PostViewHolder", "");
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        username = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textText);
        postPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postPhoto);
    }


}}
```

And for the transition I have this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostViewActivity.class);

    ImageView placeImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.postPhoto);
    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textText);

    Pair<View, String> imagePair = Pair.create((View) placeImage, getString(R.string.transition_image));
    Pair<View, String> holderPair = Pair.create((View) textView, getString(R.string.transition_username));

    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, imagePair, holderPair);
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(MainActivity.this, intent, options.toBundle());
```

But now I need a `OnClickListener` to connect this. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an `OnClickListener` to your adapter as a constructor param (or write a setter), and bind it to your `itemView` in `onBindViewHolder()`:

For example:

```
List<Post> posts;
View.OnClickListener listener;

public ListAdapter(List<Post> posts, View.OnClickListener listener) {
    Log.d("ListAdapter", "");
    this.posts = posts;
    this.listener = listener;
}

// ...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder postViewHolder, int i) {
    Log.d("onBindView", "");
    postViewHolder.username.setText(posts.get(i).getUsername());
    postViewHolder.text.setText(posts.get(i).getText());
    postViewHolder.time.setText(Long.toString(posts.get(i).getTime()));
    postViewHolder.postPhoto.setImageResource(posts.get(i).returnIMG());

    postViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Instantiating your adapter in `MainActivity`:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(posts, new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the onClick part works now. But the transition makes some problems. I've put the windowContentTransitions in the style.xml(v21) to true, both ImageView and TextView have the same transitionName and the Java code should also be working.. But the activity gets started. Just without the animation.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach could be letting the adapter handle the listener, (assuming that your RecyclerView has more than one element)

```
List<Post> posts;
Context context;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Post> posts) {
Log.d("ListAdapter", "");

this.context = context;
this.posts = posts;
}

//  ...
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder postViewHolder, int i) {
Log.d("onBindView", "");
postViewHolder.username.setText(posts.get(i).getUsername());
postViewHolder.text.setText(posts.get(i).getText());
postViewHolder.time.setText(Long.toString(posts.get(i).getTime()));
postViewHolder.postPhoto.setImageResource(posts.get(i).returnIMG());
postViewHolder.cv.setOnClickListener(onClickListener(i));
}
```

and then (again, assuming your recycler view has more than one element, each having a different image)

```
public View.OnClickListener onClickListener(final int i) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             switch(i){
                case  0:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostViewActivity.class);

                    ImageView placeImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.postPhoto);
                    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textText);

                    Pair<View, String> imagePair = Pair.create((View) placeImage, getString(R.string.transition_image));
                    Pair<View, String> holderPair = Pair.create((View) textView, getString(R.string.transition_username));

                     ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, imagePair, holderPair);
                     ActivityCompat.startActivity((Activity) context, intent, options.toBundle());
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

If you are not seeing the animation, you could maybe include

```
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(
TransitionInflater.from(this).
inflateTransition(R.transition.name_of_your_transition));
```

inside of the onCreate method of PostViewActivity